# У каких android-устройств отсутствует IMEI?

Tags: android, tablet

Я правильно понимаю, IMEI есть лишь у устройств, у которых есть GSM модуль (можно звонить с SIM)?

Если да, то как в манифесте запретить скачивание для устройств без этого модуля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы так:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Версия про отсутствие IMEI у устройств без GSM модуля верная?

Comment: не обязательно GSM модуль, IMEI есть у устройств со спутниковой связью. Судя по аббривиатуре данный номер присущь всем мобильным устройствам.

Comment: @Миха, по-другому никак не ограничить набор устройств через манифест. Кроме того, я не могу найти ни одного спутникового Android устройства. Только чехлы, предоставляющие Android смартфону спутниковую связь.

Comment: Просто в приложении при запуске реализована функция запоминания IMEI телефона. На некоторых планшетах (именно без GSM модуля), приложение вылетает на этом этапе... вот и возникла версия, что на некоторых таблетках IMEI просто не предусмотрен....